# Errors trying to declare array in class definition

Tags: c++, arrays, class, initialization

I've been trying to get this class to have a private array data member for the past hour, but it's refusing to work. I don't want to use
    array[5] mapArray;
because then I don't get the array member functions.

Here is the code I am using at the moment.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <fstream>

class Map {
public:
    void scanFile();
private:
    size_t columns = 20;
    size_t rows = 20;
    array <int, 5> mapArray;
};



int main() {
    Map myMap;
}
```

And here are some example errors I am getting in Visual Studio.

```
1>x:\aerofs\gt\ece 2036\lab03\map.cpp(12): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
1>x:\aerofs\gt\ece 2036\lab03\map.cpp(12): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>x:\aerofs\gt\ece 2036\lab03\map.cpp(12): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
```

Comment: The `array` class is defined in the `std` namespace, so try `std::array`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize the name actually came from the std space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got compilation error. It is because array is defined in namespace std. Either add

```
using namespace std;
```

at the top of your file or add `std::` before you use any type defined in there:

```
std::array< int, 5> mapArray;
```

The latter is preferred because you don't have to bring all symbols from the standard library just to use it's `array` type.

Answer (score 1):

Standard STL classes, including [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), are part of the **`std::` namespace**.

So, you can simply add the `std::` namespace qualifier to your `array` data member:

```
std::array<int, 5> mapArray;
```